# Where do I put the subject alternative names for my ssl using apache

Tags: apache, ssl, config

I purchased an SSL certificate and I have some subject alternative names for it but I'm not sure where to put them in the config file. Each site is hosted on the same server and they all correspond to one another. They are all basically the same site just for different uses/marketing reasons
SUBJECT ALTERNATIVE NAMES: www.example2.com, www.otherexample.com, www.helpwithSANs.com

```
VirtualHost IP:portServerName www.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path_to_cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path_to_key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path_to_whateverthisis
```

So my question is where or how do I use the SUBJECT ALTERNATIVE NAMES so the cert will work on all the sites.

Comment: the alternative names have to be embedded in the cert at the time it's generated. You can't do ANYTHING in apache that would "impose" a new alternative name on the cert. If this were possible, you could trivially buy a cert for `foobar.net`, then impose 'microsoft.com' as an alternative.

Comment: Makes sense, so I don't need to do anything because those SAN's are part of the certs? Thanks.

Comment: This would probably be better on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the question about configuring multiple hosts for your existing cert that has multiple SANs, or how to "add" SANs to your existing cert (which isn't possible)?

Comment: @Bruno I thought I had to include SAN's in the config file. I didn't know that they were a part of the cert itself and that I didn't need to do anything.

Comment: Look at the `ServerName` option (and named-based virtual hosts, even without SNI) for the config. For the cert, you'll need those names in the cert, so check with your CA.